# States visit order in a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

[image]

Ok so we have a labyrinth with 6 possible states plus the exit position and we want **to visit the state number 5, but not the death trap(6)** and then **exit the labyrinth through exit state**, starting state is 1 as shown.
The transition probabilities are given below:

$p_{exit/exit}=1 $ , $p_{66}=1  ,p_{12}=1 , p_{21}=p_{23}=1/2 , p_{32}=p_{34}=p_{35}=1/3,p_{43}=p_{47}=1/2,p_{56}=p_{53}=1/2$
Ok so i am trying really hard to calculate this. What i have so far is this(i think):

P(visit on **exit** before 6|$X_0=5$)

But i am really having a hard time calculating this probability since after position 5 we could visit positions 1,2,3 and 4 infinite times before we reach the exit positions. Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Yes: compute $e_x=P(\text{exits without visiting}\ 6\mid X_0=x)$ for every $x$ in $\{3,4,5\}$, these solve a linear system and you are after $e_5$.

Comment: For example, $e_5=\frac12e_3$ (why?), $e_3=\frac13e_3+\frac13e_4+\frac13e_5$ (why?) and $e_4=\frac12+\frac12e_3$ (why?), hence...

Comment: Why we don't need the $e_1,e_2$?? Plus i don't quite understand how the above linear system is constructed...

Comment: Markov property after one step of the chain. And $e_1$ and $e_2$ are not needed since after a step $3\to2$ one must pass by $3$ again before exiting the labyrinth or visiting $6$.

Comment: Did you apply the general theory in the answer you accepted, to compute the desired mean exit time? How did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expanding on Did’s comments]

Define $e_k = \Pr(\text{exits safely}\mid X_0=k)$. Using the usual method of conditioning on the first step, we compute $$e_3 = \sum_{k=1}^5\Pr(\text{exits without visiting 6}\mid X_1=k)\Pr(X_1=k\mid X_0=3).$$ By the Markov property, $\Pr(\text{exits safely}\mid X_1=k) = \Pr(\text{exits safely}\mid X_0=k)$, so we have $$e_3 = \frac13 e_2+\frac13 e_4+\frac13 e_5.$$ However, $e_2=e_3$ because the system must always enter state $3$ before exiting or hitting the trap, therefore $$e_3 = \frac13 e_3+\frac13 e_4+\frac13 e_5.$$ Similar calculations produce $e_4 = \frac12 e_3+\frac12$ and $e_5 = \frac12 e_3$. Solve the resulting system of linear equations for $e_5$.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the **canonical form of Transition Matrix of absorbing Markov chains.**

The general theory is as follows: 
Let $ P =  \begin{pmatrix}Q&R\\0&I_r\\ \end{pmatrix}$ be a transistion matrix with have t transient states and r absorbing states,

where $Q$ is a t-by-t matrix, $R$ is a nonzero t-by-r matrix, $0$ is an r-by-t zero matrix, and $I_r$ is the r-by-r identity matrix.

Thus, Q describes the probability of transitioning from some transient state to another while R describes the probability of transitioning from some transient state to some absorbing state.

The value of $P^n$ is given by \begin{pmatrix}Q^n&(I-Q)^{-1}R\\0&I_r\\ \end{pmatrix}

The matrix $(I-Q)^{-1}$ is called the fundamental matrix $F$ and $FR$ gives the probability of eventual absorption into an absorbing state from a transient state.